# How do I fetch the particular tag value that is present multiple times in the XML - Groovy Script?

Tags: xml, dom, groovy, soapui

I have XML content like below.

```
<root>
<customerObjectRelationship>
                       <customerObject>
                          <effectiveTimestamp>2018-03-06T10:17:35.557Z</effectiveTimestamp>
                          <expirationTimestamp>9999-12-31T23:59:59.999Z</expirationTimestamp>
                          <transactionId>68216709</transactionId>
                          <id>12340007</id>
                          <classification>MEM</classification>
                          <type>ACCT</type>
                       </customerObject>
    </customerObjectRelationship>
    <customerObjectRelationship>
                       <customerObject>
                          <effectiveTimestamp>2018-03-06T10:17:28.386Z</effectiveTimestamp>
                          <expirationTimestamp>9999-12-31T23:59:59.999Z</expirationTimestamp>
                          <transactionId>68216647</transactionId>
                          <id>12340005</id>
                          <classification>ENT</classification>
                          <type>FCTY</type>
                       </customerObject>
    </customerObjectRelationship></root>
```

In the above XML, I need to fetch the **id** tag value of **type = 'ACCT'**. Similarly there will be multiple types available in the XML. Based on the type code input, I need to fetch the respective  value using Groovy script.

I tried with the following script but not able to reach the destination.

```
def nodes = resultsXml.getDomNodes( "//*:customerObject/*:type" )
for( node in nodes )
{
    def value = com.eviware.soapui.support.xml.XmlUtils.getNodeValue( node )
    log.info (value)
}
```

What else need to be included in the above logic?

Thanks.

Comment: Got answer .. ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using [XmlSlurper](http://groovy-lang.org/processing-xml.html#_xmlparser_and_xmlslurper) for this use case.

Once parsed, you can apply functional filter and map operations on the nodes of interest via the `findAll` and `collect` methods.

```
def xml = '''<customerObjectRelationship>
               <customerObject>
                 <effectiveTimestamp>2018-03-06T10:17:35.557Z</effectiveTimestamp>
                 <expirationTimestamp>9999-12-31T23:59:59.999Z</expirationTimestamp>
                 <transactionId>68216709</transactionId>
                 <id>12340007</id>
                 <classification>MEM</classification>
                 <type>ACCT</type>
               </customerObject>
             </customerObjectRelationship>
             <customerObjectRelationship>
               <customerObject>
                 <effectiveTimestamp>2018-03-06T10:17:28.386Z</effectiveTimestamp>
                 <expirationTimestamp>9999-12-31T23:59:59.999Z</expirationTimestamp>
                 <transactionId>68216647</transactionId>
                 <id>12340005</id>
                 <classification>ENT</classification>
                 <type>FCTY</type>
                </customerObject>
             </customerObjectRelationship>'''

def resultsXml = new XmlSlurper().parseText("<root>$xml</root>")
def customerObjects = resultsXml.customerObjectRelationship.customerObject

def ids = customerObjects.findAll { it.type.text() == 'ACCT' } // only nodes of type ACCT
                         .collect { it.id.text() } // get the <id> tag value

assert ids == ['123400007']
```

Note that for this example, I wrapped the XML snippet in an arbitrary `<root>` tag so that it was a valid XML document, but use whichever parse method is appropriate for your situation.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use `xmlslurper` or `xmlparser`.

Simple Code :

```
def root = new XmlSlurper().parse(new File ('test.xml'))

root.customerObjectRelationship.customerObject.find{ it.type == 'ACCT' }.id.each{

    println it
}
```